# Testing php mail() in localhost problem

Tags: php, sendmail, email

Hey guys, recently I just installed msmtp in linux and I even send a mail from the terminal and it worked:

```
echo -e "Subject: Test Mail\r\n\r\nThis is a test mail" |msmtp --debug --from=default -t username@gmail.com
```

But in php, after editing the php.ini file to have this:

```
sendmail_path = '/usr/bin/msmtp -t'
```

and using this piece of code:

```
<?php
if ( mail ( 'myemail@gmail.com', 'Test mail from localhost', 'Working Fine.' ) ){
echo 'Mail sent';
}
else{
echo 'Error. Please check error log.';
}

?>
```

I get the Mail sent message but don't receive a message in my inbox. Not even in the spam folder. Anything wrong I'm doing?

msmtp configuration file:

```
defaults
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

account default
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
auth on user myemail@gmail.com
password password
from myemail@gmail.com
logfile /var/log/msmtp.log
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. Your script says the half solution.. Check your apache error logs, not the msmtp ones, if they even exist.. :) 
My log file said:

```
"msmtp: /etc/msmtprc: must be owned by you"
```

Which was correct actually, my msmtp config file at /etc/msmtp was not owned by http.

My php.ini file is like this:

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/bin/msmtp -C /etc/msmtprc -t"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns TRUE if the mail was
>   successfully accepted for delivery,
>   FALSE otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just
>   because the mail was accepted for
>   delivery, it does NOT mean the mail
>   will actually reach the intended
>   destination.

So, basically this means that message was forwarded to mail transfer tool which in your case is `/usr/bin/msmtp`. Probably there is nothing wrong with your code. I'd say the appropriate place to look is `/var/log/mail.err` or other mail related logs.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs my Mail.err is empty.

Comment: Perhaps logging is done to a different file. First of all, have you configured msmtp? Conf example: http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/doc/msmtprc.txt

Comment: Yup I think so: here is what's inside the file:defaults
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
 
account default
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
auth on
user myemail@gmail.com
password ***
from myemail@gmail.com
logfile /var/log/msmtp.log

Comment: Ok, then what /var/log/msmtp.log tells you? Have you tried to execute msmtp from command line just to make sure that it actually works?

Comment: Yes I did from the command line and it worked( even stated that in my question). I'm checking msmtp.log now.

Comment: msmtp.log doesn't exist.

Comment: Perhaps because of the permissions? Can you try to move the log to /tmp folder and run your php script again?